# React- How to solve Unhandled Rejection (Error): Actions must be plain objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

When I dispatch the action, release summary I'm having the following erro "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions." and I have no idea what could be causing this problem
below the code that dispatches the action:

```
const aula = useSelector((state) => state.sumario.aula);

const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function handleSubmit({ sumario }) {
    dispatch(lancarSumario(aula[0].id, sumario));
  }
```

the reducer's actions:

```
export function carregarDadosSumario(curso, disciplina, aula) {
  return {
    type: '@sumario/CARREGAR_DADOS_SUMARIO_REQUEST',
    payload: { curso, disciplina, aula },
  };
}

export function lancarSumario(aula, conteudo) {
  return {
    type: '@sumario/LANCAR_SUMARIO_REQUEST',
    payload: { conteudo, aula },
  };
}
```

The reducer:

```
import produce from 'immer';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  curso: null,
  disciplina: null,
  aula: null,
};

export default function user(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  return produce(state, (draft) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case '@sumario/CARREGAR_DADOS_SUMARIO_REQUEST': {
        draft.curso = action.payload.curso;
        draft.disciplina = action.payload.disciplina;
        draft.aula = action.payload.aula;
        break;
      }

      case '@sumario/LANCAR_SUMARIO_REQUEST': {
        break;
      }

      default:
    }
  });
}
```

My saga:

```
import { takeLatest, all, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

import api from '../../../services/api';

export function carregarDadosSumario() {}

export function* lancarSumario({ payload }) {
  try {
    const { conteudo, aula } = payload;

    const response = yield call(api.post, 'sumarios/new_sumario', {
      conteudo,
      aula,
    });

    console.log(response);
  } catch (err) {
    toast.error('Falha ao lançar sumário, verifique seus dados');
  }
}
export default all([
  takeLatest('@sumario/CARREGAR_DADOS_SUMARIO_REQUEST', carregarDadosSumario),
  takeLatest('@sumario/LANCAR_SUMARIO_REQUEST', lancarSumario),
]);
```

the createStore file:

```
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

import createStore from './createStore';
import persistReducers from './persistReducers';

import rootReducer from './modules/rootReducer';
import rootSaga from './modules/rootSaga';

const sagaMonitor =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
    ? console.tron.createSagaMonitor()
    : null;

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware({ sagaMonitor });

const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware];

const store = createStore(persistReducers(rootReducer), middlewares);
const persistor = persistStore(store);

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export { store, persistor };
```

the createStore index.js file:

```
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

import createStore from './createStore';
import persistReducers from './persistReducers';

import rootReducer from './modules/rootReducer';
import rootSaga from './modules/rootSaga';

const sagaMonitor =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
    ? console.tron.createSagaMonitor()
    : null;

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware({ sagaMonitor });

const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware];

const store = createStore(persistReducers(rootReducer), middlewares);
const persistor = persistStore(store);

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export { store, persistor };
```